# Heroku run rake db:migrate error with "no such file to load -- bundler/setup"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to do a "heroku run rake db:migrate", and get this error:

```
es-MacBook-Pro:project e$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
(in /app)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler/setup
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea how to interpret this error. Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Wild guess but try `heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate` and see how it goes.

Comment: Hmm. it says: Running bundle exec rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
bash: bundle: command not found

Comment: That's weird, how come you don't have bundler in your instance?

Comment: Shoot, maybe that may be the core of the problem? Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, if not even bundler is in there, there could be something wrong with the dyno itself.

Comment: OK, the problem seems to come from my attempt to install Heroku buildpack. I created another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112050/heroku-error-when-trying-to-use-custom-buildpack