# error when trying to use custom buildpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I'm trying to use phantom.js custom buildpack on Heroku (https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs)

I followed the directions and created a project with

```
heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack http://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
```

But when I do that everything seems to go wrong. I initially thought it was some other problem([Heroku run rake db:migrate error with "no such file to load -- bundler/setup"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111696/heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-error-with-no-such-file-to-load-bundler-setup)) but realized after creating a new app without the buildpack that it is the buildpack that is causing the problem.

Basically when I use the buildpack, everything goes wrong: None of my processes gets launched, bundle process doesn't work, etc.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Without the benefit of seeing any logs, if it is in fact a buildpack issue then you should contact the buildpack maintainer first: [@stomita](https://github.com/stomita)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

1. Run `heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack http://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git` to create a new Heroku app on your Heroku account.
2. Go to Heroku and find your app repository.
3. Check out `git@heroku.com:stark-mist-2296.git` and change into the clone directory.
4. Run `rails new .` to create a new blank Rails app.
5. Change `Gemfile` to use Postgres on Heroku—`pg` instead of `sqlite3`.
6. Run `git push origin master`.

You should see a blank Rails app.

It could be that you are not using the `pg` gem on Heroku.

**References**

- [Heroku.com, "Configuration and Config Vars"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)